# How do I find the profile page of Google Chrome

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome

I am using Ubuntu Linux

I recently started using a separate google profile for school using

```
 google-chrome --user-data-dir="~/.config/google-chrome/users/school/"
```

It was working fine until I needed to get to the profile directory. I expected "~/.config/google-chrome/users/school/" to be at "/home/username/.config/google-chrome/users/school" but its not.

I changed the shortcut but now I need to copy the data over.

I couldn't find the answer in any of the `about:about` pages.

Also, if I go to `~/.config/google-chrome/users/school/` in the browser of Google Chrome, it still shows a blank directory (it redirects me to `/home/username/.config/google-chrome/users/school` like you'd expect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with the double quotes, when you put a ~ into a double quoted string, bash doesn't expand to home.

For example, this line doesn't work:

```
cat "~/.bashrc"
```